# Install the latest tomcat version

Tags: elementary-os, tomcat

I'm needing a tomcat version which supports JDK 8. So since I was using tomcat6, I need to switch to tomcat 7.

The problem comes because, when I install it using:

```
apt-get install tomcat7
```

The version I get is `7.0.26`, and as you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19243458/tomcat7-not-compiling-jsp-examples/21322569#21322569), this version doesn't have JDK8 support yet.

So I need to update/install to/the newest version of tomcat 7 to ensure about it (released of course).

The only requirement by my side is to install it as apt-get does, I mean, being able to use it as service (`service tomcat7 start`, and all this stuff), so don't want to install it by downloading, unzip and run.

I've tried to look for another repositories and then run apt-get, but I couldn't do it (tried **to add** another repository, but didn't work...)

Could you explain me how to do it?

Thank you in advance

PS: just to clarify, this is expected to run in `Elementary OS`, but the real target OS is a `Guadalinex` distro ("spanish" (andalusian) distro, based on Ubuntu), so could you tell me if I can use the same steps for this OS too? (Thanks!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't quite as simple as using `apt-get`, but the result will be the same. If you download the packages for Tomcat 7.0.62 from [Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat7), they should install fine in elementary OS and support Java 8.

You'll need to click on the little triangle to the left of "The Wily Werewolf", and download the `.deb` files you need: at least [`libservlet3.0-java`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libservlet3.0-java_7.0.62-1_all.deb), [`libtomcat7-java`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libtomcat7-java_7.0.62-1_all.deb), [`tomcat7-common`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/tomcat7-common_7.0.62-1_all.deb) and [`tomcat7`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/tomcat7_7.0.62-1_all.deb). You can then install them using

```
dpkg -i libservlet3.0-java_7.0.62-1_all.deb libtomcat7-java_7.0.62-1_all.deb tomcat7-common_7.0.62-1_all.deb tomcat7_7.0.62-1_all.deb
```

Comment: after installing it as you said, I can start it but got some errores. After checking it, I found my tomcat is running (`service tomcat7 status` say it), but if I run `/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/configtest.sh` it warns me of some folders that don't exist, plus the `/conf/server.xml` file neither (nor the `conf` folder). Any idea about why is this happening? =(

Comment: What does `ls -ld /var/lib/tomcat7/conf` say? It should be a link to `/etc/tomcat7` where you should find the configuration files... If not, try `dpkg --purge tomcat7` followed by `dpkg -i tomcat7_7.0.62-1_all.deb` to reinstall the `tomcat7` package completely (that's the one containing the configuration).

Comment: `ls` says it exist, but this is not the path where `configtest.sh` is trying to find it! (`/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/server.xml`)

Comment: Ah, I see; checking on my system indicates that `configtest.sh` doesn't work with the way the packages are set up in Debian and its derivatives (including Ubuntu and elementary OS). What errors do you get when starting Tomcat?

Comment: I get no errors at launch, but when trying to access to my JSP app (tested in tomcat6 before needed JDK8), it says it cannot load some clases (`error 500`) and doesn't give any code line of my files in the stacktrace. PS: I'm starting tomcat using `service tomcat7 start`.

Comment: That's the correct way to start Tomcat, no problem there. `/var/lib/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out` will probably give you a better idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24436/discussion-between-btc-sources-and-stephen-kitt).